# Illegal Start of Simple Expression: Option Type and Ellipsis

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, ellipsis

New to Scala and just began the scala.Option Cheat Sheet.  However, this code is throwing an error in the sbt console.

```
def option[A, X](o: Option[A])(none: => X, some: => A => X): X = ...
```

The error is

> error: illegal start of simple expression

the up-arrow points to the ellipsis. The fix seems simple, but as a newbie, it currently eludes me

Comment: `= ...` is not a valid function declaration. Either you implement the function body of you use `???` to make it 'not yet implemented' (compiles, but throws exception at runtime).

Comment: Thanks. `???` did the trick. Also, after viewing the examples more carefully, it's appears the author didn't attend for some of the code to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...` is not a valid Scala expression. If you want a function with an "unknown" implementation you can use `???`:

```
def option[A, X](o: Option[A])(none: => X, some: => A => X): X = ???
```

The goal of this function is apparently to take a function as parameter and to apply either `none` or `some` depending on the content of the option. You can implement it using pattern matching:

```
def option[A, X](o: Option[A])(none: => X, some: => A => X): X = o match {
  case Some(a) => some(a)
  case None => none
}
```

Comment: Or using existing `.fold`: `o.fold(none)(some)`. btw, I would write `A => B` instead of `=> A => B`.